# Good Tutorials/Links for Sammy.js

Tags: sammy.js

I would like to learn sammy.js. Is there any good websites/tutorials/links recommended to learn sammy.js? Would really appreciate it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try [their website](http://sammyjs.org/).... [they seem to be well documented](http://sammyjs.org/docs).  Google (surprisingly) [could be of help as well](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-an-introduction-to-sammy-js/).